# Error with B2 storage and jclouds with multipart() option

Tags: jclouds

If I use jclouds with the multipart() option to upload a file to b2, I get an error like below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: large files must have at least 2 parts
    at org.jclouds.b2.handlers.ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.refineException(ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.b2.handlers.ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.handleError(ParseB2ErrorFromJsonContent.java:58)
    at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:138)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:107)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:74)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.finishLargeFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.b2.blobstore.B2BlobStore.completeMultipartUpload(B2BlobStore.java:356)
    at org.jclouds.blobstore.internal.BaseBlobStore.putMultipartBlob(BaseBlobStore.java:376)
    at org.jclouds.blobstore.internal.BaseBlobStore.putMultipartBlob(BaseBlobStore.java:347)
    at org.jclouds.b2.blobstore.B2BlobStore.putBlob(B2BlobStore.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.putBlob(Unknown Source)
    at b2.NewMain.runMain(NewMain.java:76)
    at b2.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.jclouds.b2.B2ResponseException: request POST https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v1/b2_finish_large_file HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400, error: B2Error{code=bad_request, message=large files must have at least 2 parts, status=400}
    ... 22 more
```

The code I'm using is like the following

```
PayloadBlobBuilder blobBuilder = blobStore.blobBuilder(remoteFileName)
        .payload(payload)
        .contentLength(payload.size());

Blob blob = blobBuilder.build();

String eTag = blobStore.putBlob(containerName, blob, multipart());
```

Same code for the same file works for aws-s3, google-cloud-storage, azureblob. I'm using **jclouds 2.1.1**. Is this a known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened [JCLOUDS-1477](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1477) to track this bug and jclouds 2.1.2-SNAPSHOT and 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT should include a fix.  Please test and report further symptoms in that issue.